# ios id doesn't convert to nsinteger

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, objective-c-blocks

I have the following response that returns from a block:

```
response: {
    error = "";
    success = 1;
}
```

I attempt to evaluate "success" but it never evaluates as equal to 1 only as "else":

```
NSLog(@"response: %@", responseObject);
        NSInteger success = (NSInteger)responseObject[@"success"];
        NSString *errorMessage = (NSString *)responseObject[@"error"];
        if (success == 0) {
            NSLog(@"success is false");
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", errorMessage);


            saveCallback(NO, [self createErrorFromDescription:errorMessage]);
        }else if (success == 1){
            NSLog(@"success is true");
            saveCallback(YES, nil);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"success is else");
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", errorMessage);

            saveCallback(NO, [self createErrorFromDescription:errorMessage]);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is **responseObject[@"success"]** nil by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSInteger` is a primitive and `id` is an object (actually a pointer to an object), in this case likely an `NSNumber`.

Directly casting the pointer to an object, to NSInteger will *not* transform it into a integer value type, it will just reinterpret the pointers memory as an integer.

To transform the number object to a integer value you would call `integerValue` on it.

(It could also be that the number is missing from the response or it could be returned as the NSNull object, hence the error checking below)

```
NSNumber *successNumber = responseObject[@"success"];
NSInteger success;
if (!successNumber || successNumber == [NSNull null]) {
    // the response doesn't contain anything for the "success" key :(
}
// if successNumber is nil, this will be 0. 
// if successNumber is the NSNull object, this will crash (unrecognized selector)
// Just be aware of both of those.
success = [successNumber integerValue];
```

Comment: Note that if responseObject is coming from a REST API or the like, it could potentially equal [NSNull null]; you need to check for that case before using the [@"success"] subscripting method. You should also ensure that each individual key that comes from your json is not NSNull.

Comment: @cdstamper You are right. I added basic checking for NSNull

Answer (score 1):

```
NSInteger success = [responseObject[@"success"] integerValue];
```

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it appears you're using raw json, you need to be very careful that you don't use a NULL value; this will result in an exception.

Since there are many types of Null in Objective C, it's best to use class introspection to make sure your objects are valid.

```
NSDictionary *responseArray = responseObject;
NSInteger success=0;

if([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    // responseObject is safe to subscript
    NSNumber *successNumber = responseObject[@"success"];

    // Use introspection; messaging nil doesn't cause an exception and returns nil
    if ([successNumber isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) 
    {
        // NSInteger is a primitive
        success = [successNumber integerValue];
    }
}

// If success is anything but zero, assume it's true
if (success)
{
    NSLog(@"success is true");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"success is false");
}
```

Presumably, your success key is either 1 or 0, so you could simplify this code a bit. In general, though, this is how you'll want to deal with objects that may be NULL rather than simply nil.